# How to right align horizontal form

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Hi can someone help me with aligh this form to the right, i give it a try(stupid one but why not to try) and set form-horizontal margin-left: some px; and it did move form but it resize input. I want to align it to a specific place.

```
<div class="container">
        <form class="form-horizontal">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="inputIme" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Ime</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3" placeholder="Ime">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="inputEmail" class="col-sm-2 control-label">E-mail</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputPassword3" placeholder="E-mail">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="inputTelefon" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Telefon</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputPassword3" placeholder="Broj Telefona">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="inputAdresa" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Adresa</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputPassword3" placeholder="Vasa Adresa">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Posalji zahtev</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>

    </div>
```

Comment: What is the expected result? Have you tried adding `dir="rtl"` and/or `.float-right` ?

Comment: That's acctualy works but im trying to align it to a specific place because i have background cover img and the image have blank part, where i want to put my form

Comment: Can you get us an image of the expected output. That would be really helpful to answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 <div class="col-sm-6 offset-sm-6">
            <form class="form-horizontal">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="inputIme" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Ime</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3" placeholder="Ime">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="inputEmail" class="col-sm-2 control-label">E-mail</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputPassword3" placeholder="E-mail">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="inputTelefon" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Telefon</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputPassword3" placeholder="Broj Telefona">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="inputAdresa" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Adresa</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputPassword3" placeholder="Vasa Adresa">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Posalji zahtev</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>

        </div>
```

> although your question is not clear to but I guess you need to shift your form at right side so you can use above code